# How to fix "String to Integer" error in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need the shipping cost to be determined by the various rates.

I've tried a hodgepodge of things for the last 5 hours.
If I'm supposed to use .to_s .to_f, I've tried and done so incorrectly.

```
if (weight < 2)

     rate = 0.10

   elsif ((weight >= 2) or (weight < 10))

     rate = 0.20

   elsif ((weight >= 10) or (weight < 40))

     rate = 0.30

   elsif ((weight >= 40) or (weight < 70))

     rate = 0.50

   elsif ((weight >= 70) or (weight < 100))

     rate = 0.75

   else (weight >= 100)

     rate = 0.90

end

rate = rate.to_i

ship_cost = weight * price * rate

ship_cost = ship_cost.to_i
```

The result is supposed to show a shipping cost after the rate is applied. I keep getting to the String to Integer error.

Comment: What's the whole error you're getting?

Comment: And also please provide samples data and specific expected results

Comment: The whole error: :in `*': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)

Comment: `[]['foo']
Traceback (most recent call last):
        6: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/bin/irb:23:in '<main>'
        5: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/bin/irb:23:in 'load'
        4: from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/irb-1.0.0/exe/irb:11:in '<top (required)>'
        3: from (irb):6
        2: from (irb):6:in 'rescue in irb_binding'
        1: from (irb):6:in '[]'
TypeError (no implicit conversion of String into Integer)`, that's a _whole error_, what you provided is not. It tells nothing to people reading your question.

Comment: /Users/gemarh/RubymineProjects/Ch4Asg.rb/Ch4Asg.rb:35:in `*': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
 from /Users/gemarh/RubymineProjects/Ch4Asg.rb/Ch4Asg.rb:35:in `<main>'

Comment: I'm really sorry, I have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: Don't worry. Check the values of `weight`, `price` and `rate`. One or more of them must be a string, which causes the error: `'a' * 'b' # => TypeError (no implicit conversion of String into Integer)`.

Comment: How do I recognize which one is a string, and how does it need to change? Or is it that I need to make it a string? I have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: Just print them before doing the multiplication. If they're numbers represented as string, you can "cast" them to integers.

Comment: Also, this line `rate=rate.to_i` will always return 0 when turning a float number between 1 and 0 to integer .

Answer (score 2):

The problem is somehow one or more variables within the multiplication is a string, which results in the `TypeError` error you're getting, as in:

```
'a' * 'b' #  '*': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
```

If you want to suppress the error, you can manually convert them into integers or floats. Meaning if the string doesn't have a numeric representation, it'll return 0:

```
'asd'.to_i  # 0
'1'.to_i.   # 1
'-9.9'.to_i # -9
'-9.9'.to_f # -9.9
```

---

Alternatively, you can handle the `rate` assignation by using a "dictionary" which holds the min and max value `weight` can be to return `X`. Creating a range from min to max and asking if it includes the value of weight you can get assign its value:

```
dict = {
  [-Float::INFINITY, 2]  => 0.10,
  [2, 10]                => 0.20,
  [10, 40]               => 0.30,
  [40, 70]               => 0.50,
  [70, 100]              => 0.75,
  [100, Float::INFINITY] => 0.90
}

p dict.find { |(start, finish), _| (start...finish).include?(-42.12) }.last # 0.1
p dict.find { |(start, finish), _| (start...finish).include?(0) }.last      # 0.1
p dict.find { |(start, finish), _| (start...finish).include?(1) }.last      # 0.1
p dict.find { |(start, finish), _| (start...finish).include?(23) }.last     # 0.3
p dict.find { |(start, finish), _| (start...finish).include?(101) }.last    # 0.9
```

Comment: Holy crap I figured it out and I can't believe it was so easy. Thank you for helping me!!!!!!

Comment: If you are using an excusive range you need to define it as `40...70` not `41...70`. Otherwise you will get the wrong values for 40.1.

Answer (score 1):

A less verbose and more idiomatically correct solution is to use a case statement  with ranges:

```
def shipping_rate(weight)
  case weight
  when 0...2
     0.10
  when 2...10
     0.20
  when 10...40
     0.30
  when 40...70
     0.50
  when 70...100
     0.75
  when 100...Float::INFINITY
     0.90
  end
end
```

Declaring a range with `...` excludes the end value. So `(40...70).cover?(70) == false`. That lets us avoid overlap issues.

```
require "minitest/autorun"
class TestShippingRate < Minitest::Test
  def test_correct_rate
    assert_equal 0.10, shipping_rate(1)
    assert_equal 0.20, shipping_rate(3)
    assert_equal 0.30, shipping_rate(39)
    assert_equal 0.50, shipping_rate(40)
    assert_equal 0.75, shipping_rate(70)
    assert_equal 0.90, shipping_rate(101)
  end
end

# Finished in 0.002255s, 443.3896 runs/s, 2660.3374 assertions/s.
# 1 runs, 6 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

If you want to use a dict like Sebastian Palma suggested you can do it with hash with ranges for keys instead:

```
def shipping_rate(weight)
  {
    0...2 => 0.10,
    2...10 => 0.20,
    10...40 => 0.30,
    40...70 => 0.50,
    70...100 => 0.75,
    100...Float::INFINITY => 0.90
  }.find { |k, v| break v if k.cover? weight }
end
```

Using `case` is a bit more flexible though as you can add a `else` condition or handle string arguments:

```
def shipping_rate(weight)
  case weight
  when 0...2
     0.10
  when 2...10
     0.20
  when 10...40
     0.30
  when 40...70
     0.50
  when 70...100
     0.75
  when 100...Float::INFINITY
     0.90
  # I'm not saying this is a good idea as the conversion should happen
  # upstream. Its just an example of what you can do
  when String
     shipping_rate(weight.to_f) # recursion
  else 
     raise "Oh noes. This should not happen."
  end
end
```

Comment: I didn't think about the ranges as keys. Pretty nice!